# grails dbm-gorm-diff is updating db

Tags: grails, database-migration

I'm using grails database-migration to update my production db, but it' presenting a weird behaviour. I ran dbm-gorm-diff and it seems to work fine, but for some reason my prod db is getting updated without I use 'dbm-update' or put it to be executed when the war file is deployed.

What I realised so far is that it seems that any operation made on the prod environment is some how triggering an update on the db. And I couldn't figure out what.

Answer (score 2):

did you set dataSource -> dbCreate to ['any other value'](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource)?

Comment: so it has nothing to do with the database-migration plugin. it's the default grails behavior.

Comment: Hum... Then what would be the right option to create the db in the first time and do not update it? 'create' or 'validate'?

Comment: if you are using database-migration, you don't want grails to change your database schema. you can use 'any other value' or remove the 'dbCreate' property. 'validate' may also work (never used it).

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that this is what's happening; that would be a very serious bug, and it would have appeared before now, unless it's a very unusual combination of settings/state/db/etc. that triggers this.

If you can isolate this to a small and repeatable example please create a bug report at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION and I'll fix it ASAP.

Comment: I tried twice, and both times it happened, the DB was updated during a dbm-gorm-diff. I'll report it.